# How could Sasuke match Lee's speed?

Tags: naruto

In episode 22 of Naruto, when Lee fights Sasuke, we have seen Lee open the first Gate, after which he claims to have supreme speed to launch his attack.

But (not far away) in episode 66, Sasuke obtains that speed, within only a month of training, while it took Lee many years of extremely hard work.

Although he had Sharingan, it doesn't mean that he can copy the speed of his opponent. How was it possible?

Answer (score 6):

- **Sasuke:**
  is a "genius" (possesses innate talent).
  is a Uchiha (somewhat the reason why he is a "genius").
- **Lee:**
  is a hard worker (his main motivation being to surpass Neji, the "genius" in his team).

Basically, Lee has no innate talent to ninjutsu or genjutsu. Thus he had to master taijutsu in order to surpass the "geniuses", and become a great ninja. This is a process that takes a lot of time.
Sasuke on the other hand does not need to work so hard in order to accomplish what Lee needs to work on for several years. Remember that he was able to master the Goukakyuu no Jutsu at a very early age.

Comment: This. He's an Uchiha, he's Sasuke and yeah, that's it. :P

Comment: His increase in speed has nothing to do with his sharingan. The fact that he is an Uchiha gives him a sort of "better chakra". As opposed to Lee's chakra, since he has no natural talent.

Comment: Perhaps Taijutsu depends on "efficient" chakra flow in your body to complement physical finesse - and the Sharingan can read and copy these patterns.

Comment: @JNat@ArturiaPendragon Do you have something to relate/refer to what you said that he could with his Sharingan to copy/boost its ability of his taijutsu? Because He is indeed from the Uchenna clan and it's gives him a significant advantage in learning genjutsu and ninjutsu but I do not remember mentioned somewhere that it is valid for taijutsu.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju: I never said that his sharingan helped him boost his speed. With it he can easily copy Lee's movements, but it does not allow him to copy his speed. However, since he is a "genius", he can achieve Lee's speed much easily. Those two points put together let him achieve Lee's speed and technique in a shorter period of time.

Comment: this is what i call sharingan spammed powerups..

Answer (score 2):

It is much like the situation Lee had with Neji, really. Neji is a true genius, the process of learning and training is fast and easy for him. Remember Neji's thoughts about geniuses and that they are unreachable bu people without talent?

Lee is a perfect example of hard-worker. He had absolutely no talent neither for ninjutsu nor for genjutsu. He trained extremely hard for *years*, and his willpower and stubbornness (and Guy-sensei) helped him to finally become what he was.

Sasuke, much like many others inUchiha clan, was a genius too. While in their first encounter his speed wasn't enough to match Lee's, in the second one, he was already able to reach the same speed. Of course, the Sharingan also helped. No, it can not "copy the speed", I think it's portrayed nicely in the anime (though I dont remember the episode), when Sasuke can see Lee's movements with Sharingan, but cannot react fast enough with his body. However, Sharingan also helps in practicing Taijutsu, because it lets it's owner learn techniques faster. Of course, it helps in battle as well, allowing to see enemy movements absolutely clear and precise, and possible copying them (Sasuke showed that in the first part on exam, when he used Sharingan to copy the answers to the test from the guy in front of him by copying his arm movements).

Comment: and Sasuke copied Lee's "Lion Combo" (Shishi Rendan) after seeing it only once and used it to defeat a Sound ninja in the Chuunin Exam.

Comment: @ArturiaPendragon It just means that he copied the technique but he just has not reached its speed at that time.

Answer (score -1):

Lee only trained for a year to get that speed. Sasuke was already faster than Lee had been when he started training. Combined with his inate talent, ability to use chakra properly and intense training, it's not that unbelievable.